# Local storage is not keeping the data after page reload

Tags: reactjs

I'm making in react a list of episodes that user would like to watch later (similar to todo app) , but after reloading the page data is not keeping in local storage.
I'm new to react, so, please help me to understand the issue.
This is my code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { RiCloseCircleLine } from "react-icons/ri";
import { TiEdit } from "react-icons/ti";

import { MyWatchListForm } from "./MyWatchListForm";

export const MyWatchListItem = ({
  watchLists,
  completeWatchList,
  removeWatchList,
  updateWatchList,
}) => {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState({
    id: null,
    value: "",
  });

  const submitUpdate = (value) => {
    updateWatchList(edit.id, value);
    setEdit({
      id: null,
      value: "",
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("my-watchList");

    const savedData = JSON.parse(data);
    setEdit(savedData);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("my-watchList", JSON.stringify(watchLists));
  });

  if (edit.id) {
    return <MyWatchListForm edit={edit} onSubmit={submitUpdate} />;
  }

  return watchLists.map((watchList, index) => (
    <div className={watchList.isComplete ? "checked" : ""} key={index}>
      <div key={watchList.id} onClick={() => completeWatchList(watchList.id)}>
        {watchList.text}
      </div>
      <div>
        <RiCloseCircleLine onClick={() => removeWatchList(watchList.id)} />
        <TiEdit
          onClick={() => setEdit({ id: watchList.id, value: watchList.text })}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
};
```

Form that is used to get the data from:

```
export const MyWatchListForm = (props) => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState(props.edit ? props.edit.value : "");

  const inputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  });

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    props.onSubmit({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000),
      text: input,
    });
    setInput("");
  };

  
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <form
      className="w-full max-w-sm flex items-center border-b border-teal-500 py-2"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      {props.edit ? (
        <>
          <input
            className="appearance-none bg-transparent border-none w-full text-gray-700 mr-3 py-1 px-2 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
            type="text"
            value={input}
            placeholder="Update the episode"
            onChange={handleChange}
            ref={inputRef}
          ></input>
          <button>Update</button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <input
            className="appearance-none bg-transparent border-none w-full text-gray-700 mr-3 py-1 px-2 leading-tight focus:outline-none"
            type="text"
            value={input}
            placeholder="Add the episode"
            onChange={handleChange}
            ref={inputRef}
          ></input>
          <button>Add</button>
        </>
      )}
    </form>
  );
};
```

And the WatchList.js file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import { MyWatchListForm } from "./MyWatchListForm";
import { MyWatchListItem } from "./MyWatchListItem";

export const MyWatchList = () => {
  const [watchLists, setWatchLists] = useState([]);

  const addWatchList = (watchList) => {
    if (!watchList.text || /^\s*$/.test(watchList.text)) {
      return;
    }
    const newWatchList = [watchList, ...watchLists];

    setWatchLists(newWatchList);
    console.log(...watchLists);
  };

  const updateWatchList = (watchListId, newValue) => {
    if (!newValue.text || /^\s*$/.test(newValue.text)) {
      return;
    }
    setWatchLists((prev) =>
      prev.map((item) => (item.id === watchListId ? newValue : item))
    );
  };

  const removeWatchList = (id) => {
    const removeArr = [...watchLists].filter(
      (watchList) => watchList.id !== id
    );
    setWatchLists(removeArr);
  };

  const completeWatchList = (id) => {
    const updatedWatchList = watchLists.map((watchList) => {
      if (watchList.id === id) {
        watchList.isComplete = !watchList.isComplete;
      }
      return watchList;
    });
    setWatchLists(updatedWatchList);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Watch later</h1>
      <MyWatchListForm onSubmit={addWatchList} />
      <MyWatchListItem
        watchLists={watchLists}
        completeWatchList={completeWatchList}
        removeWatchList={removeWatchList}
        updateWatchList={updateWatchList}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Is `watchLists` an array? If so how are you using an array to set edit value which clearly is an object?

Comment: still the edit function is well working . I'm getting the problem only with keeping the data in local storage

Comment: Can you try logging the data in watchlists before setting it to localstorage and check if it actually has any data while being set?

Comment: yes, if I log the data before setting it to localstorage I'm getting the array of objects with the data inserted

Comment: [{…}]
 id: 7252
text: "episode 23"

Comment: What is the last log you are getting? Is it an empty array or an array with data? I am asking this just to make sure the data thatg this component receives is not overwriting the actual localstorage data since you are using 2 useEffects for setting and getting the data.

Comment: I removed useEffect for setItem, but still get an empty array after page reload

Comment: Can you log the data in watchlists every time the component renders and make sure that the data is not empty for the last render (which is the last log).

Comment: I have a working code in code sandbox here → https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-kepler-e5jun. Check it out and let me know if thats what you are looking for.

Comment: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1573, text: "epi3"}
1: {id: 2687, text: "epi2"}
2: {id: 727, text: "epi1"}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: no, this is not what I'm looking for. Please check your code. After refreshing the page all the data disappear. But I need it to be shown even after the page was refreshed

Comment: Ok got it. In that case you need to store the data in the parent component since it is the one passing watchlist as a prop to the child. Checkout my code now. I have edited it.

Comment: What was happening is that the parent was always resetting the value to default every time the page loaded thus overwriting the localstorage with an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue with your code is this snippet:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("my-watchList", JSON.stringify(watchLists));
  });
```

Every time the state get's updated, this useEffect runs and it replaces the content of localStorage to the values which you are getting in watchlists since you are not providing a dependancy array to the useEffect.

Comment: watchLists is an array with list of episodes added, why does it give the empty array? How this can be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide the parent component code also from where you are passing props to `MyWatchListItem`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by changing the initial state in MyWatchList as below:

```
export const MyWatchList = () => {
  const [watchLists, setWatchLists] = useState(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("my-watchList");
    return data ? JSON.parse(data) : [];
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("my-watchList", JSON.stringify(watchLists));
  }, [watchLists]);
```

Comment: you can approve your own solution to guide people who may have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Using the useEffect hook without a dependency array is never a good idea. It basically runs on every render. Actually, goal of the useEffect is to solve this problem. Remove your useEffect and try like this;

```
const submitUpdate = (value) => {
  updateWatchList(edit.id, value);
  setEdit({
    id: null,
    value: "",
  });

  localStorage.setItem("my-watchList", JSON.stringify(watchLists));

};
```

Comment: This doesn't help. Still getting the empty array after reloading :(

Comment: `useEffect(() => {localStorage.setItem("my-watchList", JSON.stringify(watchLists));});`

Have you removed this part?